# PHP PDO, request users name

Tags: php, pdo

I have php dpo request:

```
<?php
    include '../reg/db.php';
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $password_hashed = $row['password'];
    $username = $row['name'];
}
```

Then, when I need to echo name of user, which just logged in, **but it shows wrong name**! (e.x. I am Alex, he write I am john (John is already in DB, dont understand why it chooses other name)

```
if ( password_verify( $_POST['password'], $password_hashed )  ) { ?>
   <div class="enterReg">
     <div class="frameworkForUser">
     <div class="usernameMargin">
     <? echo $username; ?>
   </div>
<? } ?>
```

**How could I get name of the user which just logged in?** Surfed the internet a bit but haven't found anything about it .-.

Comment: `why it chooses other name` Because you select __all users__ from DB. And if there will be 10K users - you will select all of them? For what?

Comment: Where does your code determine whoch user is currently logged in?

Comment: @u_mulder how could I choose necessary user, which logged in?

Comment: what are u saving in your session?

Comment: @devpro nothing

Comment: so how can u check who is logged in

Comment: @devpro so what I need to do is: 1. save my session somehow 2. via session check who is logged ? Can I write php variable into  sth like this : $db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); ?

Comment: u can each n everything, but u are not using session , where is your login page?

Comment: @devpro I remember user via cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please reference the user properties that you want to select the SQL queries using their post variables.

something like:

```
$username =$_POST['username'];
$password = password=$_POST['password'];

 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username' and password= '$password'");
```

While this might solve your problem but Please do not 
use this code in production for fear of **sql inject,html scripting Attack** etc.

You can better use **Mysqli Prepared statement or better use PDO.**

to sanitize against html elements attack, you can use strip_tags() function

Example

```
$username =strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags(password=$_POST['password']);
```

**Updated Answer**

**Option 1 using sessions**

```
<?php


    include '../reg/db.php';
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


if ($username == ''){
echo "username is empty";
exit();
}


if ($password == ''){
echo "Password is empty";
exit();
}



$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username and password = :password');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$row = $result->fetch();

if( $count == 1 ) {
echo "login sucessful";
// Redirect me to a Dasboard.php to display the login user
echo "<script>window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";


//Initialize a session
session_start()

//Prevent session Fixation Attack using session generated Id;
session_regenerate_id();

// pass users info in a session if things where ok.
// Prevent xss Attack using Htmlspecialchar or htmlentities() functions

$_SESSION['name'] = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
$_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($row['username']);

// Do not pass users password in a session
//$_SESSION['password']=htmlspecialchars($row['password']);

}
else {

echo "<font color=red>Either Username or Password is Wrong</font>";
}


?>
```

on **dashboard.php** you can now have the code below depending on your implementations.....

```
// initialize sessions

session_start();

// the the authenticated users parameters

Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?><br>
userName: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?><br>
```

**option 2  No session usage**

```
<?php


    include '../reg/db.php';
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);


if ($username == ''){
echo "username is empty";
exit();
}


if ($password == ''){
echo "Password is empty";
exit();
}



$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username and password = :password');

        $result->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$row = $result->fetch();

if( $count == 1 ) {
echo "login sucessful";
// Redirect me to a Dasboard.php to display the login user
//echo "<script>window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";


$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
$username = htmlspecialchars($row['username']);

echo "userame: $username </br>";
echo "Name: $name </br>";


}
else {

echo "<font color=red>Either Username or Password is Wrong</font>";
}


?>
```

Let me know if you are having any issue. Remember the password in the code is not hashed. it assumes plain text password is in your database..

Comment: I use PDO but how via PDO to choose just logged in user for my site to give me back right name of the user?

Comment: I will provide you with two solution in less than 5 minute so hang on ....

Comment: solution has been posted. please see updated section of my answer and let me know

Comment: Is it possible to use cookies instead session?

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you for your answer much!

Comment: They are always two kind of secured authentications. Session based login and Token based login.